# What Protocol to use for chat? webRTC or Websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc

I'm creating a Chat site that will be able to do, Video, Audio and Text Chatting. I'm currently using Websockets for Text Chatting. I need to know what is best at Video, Audio and Text Chatting. Which one is more effiecint. Should I use Websockets for all of them or webRTC for Video and Audio and Websockets for Text Chat. I can do both and wouldn't like to have to re-write my text chat for webRTC but if it is a better option then I will.
**EDIT:** I've just found out about binaryJS, Is this a better and easier alternative to webRTC?
Thanks,
@_C1D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By embedding your video and audio streams in websockets, you'll have a simpler system but everything will have to pass through your server.

WebRTC allows for a direct connection between pairs, so you'd get much better results using it.

Note also, but you probably know it already, that everything webRTC is just emerging.

Regarding the question in edit, about binaryJS : I never tried that but it doesn't look like a deal changer, just a facility for using websockets.

Comment: So webRTC won't require a server?

Comment: You have to establish the connection, with the help of ICE servers (you may use Google's ones) but past that the streams flow "directly" from one browser to the other without having to go through your server.

Comment: With WebRTC you will probably only need the server to manage the connection between clients, not the actual Data transfer. In terms of efficiency it is a better answer, however, support is a bit shaky.

Comment: The "a bit shaky" point is important. Even if you're used to deal with emerging technologies, you might find a few details painful to handle.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. webRTC is only supported on chrome 26, which would be a problem. Do you know of any examples of websocket video transfer working right?

Comment: For now [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/) is probably the reference regarding [examples and tutorial on WebRTC](http://www.google.com/search?q=html5rocks+webrtc). I didn't try coding webrtc on Firefox but [it should be about available](http://www.webrtc.org/firefox).

Comment: I think I'm going to use webRTC for video and audio. To be honest I managed to get a websocket video client working but it was horribly laggy, and mind you I was on localhost.